# Word for accepting a report via a vote

Tags: single-word-requests

I was a member of a student government committee created to write a lengthy report on fee usage.  At the end of the process, the Senate voted to accept the report.
In the sentence; **"The report was accepted by the Senate"** is there a word better than **accepted** for implying/showing that the report was voted on? I could write it out, but I'm listing this on a resume and would like to be concise.

Comment: I understand the need to be concise, but if the vote was unanimous I'd include/emphasize that point by using the active voice with @WS2 's good answer: "By unanimous vote the Senate [ultimately] adopted the report//[Ultimately] The Senate unanimously adopted the Report."

Comment: There is actually nothing wrong with using *accept,* as that could not happen without a vote.

Comment: @PapaPoule: But did they adopt it? Or did they just (unanimously) accept it? The OP says they voted to *accept* it. It has (apparently) been accepted, not rejected - and not adopted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual term in Britain would be ***adopted***.

***The report was adopted by the Senate***.

It is covered by OED sense 8 of the verb *adopt*.

8. trans. To approve or accept (a report, proposal, resolution, etc.) formally; to ratify.

> 1736   A. Campbell Further Explic. 6   It was agreed, that..they
>   should narrate in their Minutes, That the Committee had not adopted
>   that Report.
>
> 1754   B. Franklin in Wks. (1887) II. 355   Plan of Union Adopted by
>   the Convention at Albany.
>
> 1864   Weekly New Mexican 3 June 1/4   The house ways and means
>   committee will report a bill having adopted the amendment permitting
>   states to tax the national banks.
>
> 1875   T. W. Higginson Young Folks' Hist. U.S. xvii. 164   His
>   resolutions were adopted by a small majority; all the younger members
>   being with him.
>
> 1906   J. Galsworthy Man of Prop. 178,   I propose then that the
>   report and accounts be adopted.
>
> 1958   Oxf. Mail 16 Aug. 8/7   The best balance sheet the club has
>   ever had was unanimously adopted at the annual general meeting of the
>   Oxford Club League.
>
> 2000   Slavic Rev. 59 861   The deputies of the Union of 17 October
>   rejected by a very large majority..the resolutions adopted at the
>   Octobrist conference organized by Guchkov.

Comment: Actually, adopt is better.

Comment: *Adopt* and *accept* are very, very different. *Adopt* means the Senate made the report its own; *accept* means it received it from its author (whose report it remains). There is actually nothing wrong with using *accept,* as that could not happen without a vote.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Whilst one cannot disagree that *adopt* in most of the examples the OED quotes implies an organisation "making the report its own", the venerable tome does give its meaning (sense 8) as *To approve or accept formally, to ratify*. There is nothing there to suggest the making of something its own. My suggestion is therefore that the spectrum of meaning of *adopt* ranges from mere acceptance to its making a report inherent to its own policy.

Comment: Approve, accept formally, and ratify are about adopting, not accepting. They are precisely about the recipient making the thing its own. What @AndrewLeach said is pertinent. If the Senate *voted to accept the report* then that's what it did; it (apparently) did not vote to adopt it.

Comment: So you think that *accepting* and *adopting* mean the same thing, at least in this context? That's apparently where we disagree.

Comment: @Drew I'm saying that's what the OED thinks. I've just deleted my previous comment because of a serious typo. I meant to say -there is no reason why you and Andrew Leach shouldn't continue to hold your view. However it came out as "no reason why you should hold that view". My apologies to both of you. But notwithstanding what you think, I'm just reporting what the OED thinks.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Sorry for the earlier typo.